# Is it possible to add custom commands to the Redis client for NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, npm

I'm using the `redis` Node package for connecting, storing and retrieving data from Redis. Is it possible to add new commands to the client as Redis introduces those commands? For example, is there a way to define the [GEOADD](http://redis.io/commands/geoadd) command on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add custom commands to the `node-redis` client. However, the [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) package offers support for the new Redis commands.

Answer (score 0):

as of version 2.8 of node-redis, it is possible to add arbitrary commands to the prototype by using Redis.addCommand(name)